# Can I update the state of a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Im new to React. Can we change the state of a prop? For eg I have 2 pieces of code

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react' 
import Print from '../components/Print/print'

const [text, setText] = useState("Hi");

<Print text = {text} />
```

**print.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Print = (props) => {
    return(
            <p>props</p>
   )

export default Print
```

Is there a way to change the state of the prop i.e use `useState()` in `print.js` to update the state. For eg can we do something like `setText(prop)` in `print.js`. If not like this then how would you trigger a state change from `print.js` for variable `tech` in `App.js` ?

Comment: Pass the setter down? Pass a different callback to proxy access to it?

Comment: On mount in Print, create a state var, set the value to the prop value. Then you can change the value in print itself without altering the prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot and shouldn't try to change the state or values of the props directly in the child component. For changing props you can pass the function as a prop and then emit the new value to that function. So the function will change your props into the parent component and it will further pass down to its child.

```
<Print text = {text} changeText = {(newVal) => setText(newVal)}/>
```

And in your child component call this `changeText` function with new value.

```
 return (
   <>
    <p>{props.text}</p>
    <div onClick={props.changeText('Hello')}>Change Text</div>
   </>
 );
```

FYI, `{props}` is an array and you can access text by `{props.text}`

Comment: Thanks..the method you mentioned worked

Comment: Welcome. Keep learning. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

- Pass text and setText in print.js through props
- then use setText to update the state of the components