# How to take onClick as an argument in component library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, arguments, storybook, react-component

I would like to able to able to trigger a function when I'm using a custom button component, adding onClick directly doesn't work.

**Button.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export interface ButtonProps {
  rounded: 'small' | 'medium' | 'full';
  label: string;
  icon?: string;
  size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'full';
  type: 'outline' | 'quiet' | 'fill';
  disabled?: boolean;
  variant: 'accent' | 'primary' | 'secondary';
}

export const Button = ({
  rounded,
  label,
  icon,
  size,
  type,
  disabled,
  variant,
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const disabledStyles = 'bg-gray-200 cursor-not-allowed';
  const sizeSmall = 'px-4 py-2';
  const sizeMedium = 'px-6 py-3';
  const sizeLarge = 'px-8 py-4';
  return (
    <>
        <button
        type="button"
        className={`rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring-[3px] inline-flex justify-center
          ${disabled === true && disabledStyles}
          ${size?.toLowerCase() === 'small' && sizeSmall}
          ${size?.toLowerCase() === 'medium' && sizeMedium}
          ${size?.toLowerCase() === 'large' && sizeLarge}`}
        >
          ${label}
        </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

I want to trigger myFunction when button is clicked

```
import {Button} from myLibraryName;

const myFunction = () => {
    console.log('function passed')
}

return <Button [arguments] />
```

Comment: You can pass onClick to your Button component and then inside that pass it on to button tag using <button onClick={props.onClick}>

Comment: you mean adding onClick?: any in ButtonProps and <button onClick={onClick} ....>?

Comment: Yes <Button onClick={myFunction}> & <button onClick={onClick}>

Comment: Like in this answer. [update prop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520682/11377682) You can pass the function as a prop. `<Button myFn = {myFunction}>` and in child, you can access it like `{props.myFn}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass down the onClick as a button prop, then in the `Button` component you need to add it to the `ButtonProps` interface. Then simply pass it down the the `button` element inside the render function.

Your **Button.tsx** will look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface ButtonProps {
  rounded: 'small' | 'medium' | 'full';
  label: string;
  icon?: string;
  size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'full';
  type: 'outline' | 'quiet' | 'fill';
  disabled?: boolean;
  variant: 'accent' | 'primary' | 'secondary';
  onClick: () => void;
}

export const Button = ({
  rounded,
  label,
  icon,
  size,
  type,
  disabled,
  variant,
  onClick,
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const disabledStyles = 'bg-gray-200 cursor-not-allowed';
  const sizeSmall = 'px-4 py-2';
  const sizeMedium = 'px-6 py-3';
  const sizeLarge = 'px-8 py-4';
  return (
    <>
        <button
        onClick={onClick}
        type="button"
        className={`rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring-[3px] inline-flex justify-center
          ${disabled === true && disabledStyles}
          ${size?.toLowerCase() === 'small' && sizeSmall}
          ${size?.toLowerCase() === 'medium' && sizeMedium}
          ${size?.toLowerCase() === 'large' && sizeLarge}`}
        >
          ${label}
        </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

and the function will be passed down like:

```
import {Button} from myLibraryName;

const myFunction = () => {
    console.log('function passed')
}

return <Button ...arguments onClick={myFunction}  />
```